# Current Location tag on google maps url not working anymore from August 2017

Tags: google-maps-urls

It was possible use an url like this:

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=44.053442,12.5046472

from August 2017 Google changed the syntax of generic url introducing the "origin" and "destination" keyword, so url SHOULD be

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin="Current+Location"&destination=44.4949881,11.2725758

Naturally this url is working fine:

samestuff&origin=44.053442,12.5046472&destination=44.4949881,11.2725758

I tried several combination of "Current Location", I tried to omit "origin", no success.

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Now it is working again. Thanks Google!

Comment: I am having his same problem. It seems google is now approximating the location with the OP method. And even if you use the JavaScript method to get - with the users permission - their coordinates, it still is only a proximate for me. Typically a few blocks away.